# Time and Date operations in R

Tags: r

I am trying to separate the date and time from the login and logout column.
I want 4 separate columns i.e. 1) login date
                               2) login time
                               3) logout date 
                               4) logout time
total data points is 15444.
i have tried using reshape and lubridate as well. Please help on this.

[image]

Comment: This should be easy with lubridate: Use `parsedatetime` first and then add the columns you need. What have you tried am what isn't working?

Comment: You've got a couple different options. If your variables are character strings, you could just split on the space. If they're a date class or POSIX class, you could use the format function. Or, if you don't want to create new variables and rebuild the dataset, you could use the separate function from the tidyr package.

Comment: hi, it would be really helpful if you share the exact code for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`as.Date(d1$login_time)`
should return the date part.

To extract the time you can use `format(as.POSIXct(d1$login_time) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")`

You can add these field to your existing data frame as follows

```
d1$login_time_Data <- as.Date(d1$login_time)
d1$login_time_Time <- format(as.POSIXct(d1$login_time) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

and likewise for `logout_time`,`login` and `logout`.

Doing so will add the columns `login_time_Data` etc. to your existing data frame.

Comment: Hi, Philip can i create a subset of it. As the as.date is giving the values . So , what more do i need to do in order to create a separate data set with login time , login date, and so on. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RishiNad extended my answer. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: @RishiNad Good to hear that I could help. Do you also want to mark my answer as "accepted"? Thx.

Comment: I have posted another question. Please have a look at it.